# Unable to use pathauto aliases for taxonomy terms in conjunction with views pages

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I'm trying to set up pathauto aliases for a number of vocabularies to work alongside corresponding view pages. However, in doing so, I'm running into a 404s ("The requested page could not be found") when visiting the view's page path on the frontend. I suspect this is due to a conflict (and likely my misunderstanding of the relationship) between the views page paths and the taxonomy term path aliases. Note that I'm going to have a number of unique layouts and field sets for the various vocabularies, which is why I'm trying to create unique view pages and paths rather than the default `taxonomy/term/%` page.

An example taxonomy alias pattern is `recipes/mealtime/[term:name]`.

Its corresponding view page path is `recipes/mealtime/%`, and it's configured with the appropriate relationship (taxonomy field on the node) and contextual filter (term name with validation on the appropriate vocabulary). When I use the view configuration to preview with a particular term, I get the expected results.

The issue, however, is that when I visit a path on the frontend, e.g. `/recipes/mealtime/lunch`, I get a 404. Note that I've ensured that the path aliases have been generated.

What is the proper way to accomplish what I've described?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you enter into Views Preview field to get the correct results? Must be sth with your Contextual config. Update the Q with that info. It doesn't seem you need Pathauto for this, but a Redirect or Global redirect modules?

Comment: have you rebuild all the path aliases? and updated the bulk? by visiting `admin/config/search/path/update_bulk`

Comment: According to [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto/issues/3207292), I seem to have misunderstood the relationship between pathauto and Views page paths. The contextual preview was working in the Views admin and I had rebuilt the paths in bulk, to no avail. In the end, I just reverted to the default `taxonomy/term/%` path in on my view's page configuration and leveraged a View Mode to accommodate the unique layouts I was seeking for term listings by content type. Cheers!